# Одинаковы ли типы const int и int в шаблонах?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Почему программа выводит `00`, ведь `const int` = `int`, то есть вызов идёт к одной и той же функции, а значит статическая переменная увеличится на единицу и должно быть `01`? Или `const int` и `int` - разные типы? Почему тогда в параметрах обычной функции они одинаковые?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f() {
    static int check = 0;
    std::cout << check++;
}

int main() {
    f<int>();
    f<const int>();
}
```

Comment: нет, можете проверить, например, с помощью ```std::is_same```

Comment: *"Почему тогда в параметрах обычной функции они одинаковые?"* Почему вы так думаете? Попробуйте `void foo(/*const*/ int x) {x = 0;}`.

Comment: По историческим причинам `const` модификатор типа параметров при объявлении функции может не соответствовать таковому при определении функции, не является частью сигнатуры и не используется при выборе подходящей перегрузки. В С вообще параметры не проверялись.

Answer (score 1):

При выведение типов параметра шаблона (если есть из чего выводить) `const` верхнего уровня игнорируется. Т.е. если функция принимает параметр типа `T`:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T) { }
```

Следующие вызовы:

```
int i = 42;
const int c = 100500;
f(i);
f(c);
f(0);
```

все приведут к тому, что тип `T` определяется как `int`. Инстанцируется только одна функция из шаблона. Если передавать тип явно (например, если нет параметров), как это сделано у вас, то безусловно разные типы (а `const int` и `int` это разные типы) породят разные функции из шаблона, т.к. эти типы не выводились автоматически из параметров при вызове.

В параметрах обычных функций типы отличающиеся только `const` верхнего уровня [неразличимы](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.load#3.4), например:

```
void f(int) {}
void f(const int) {}
```

Эти функции будут восприняты компилятором как одинаковые функции (породит ошибку компиляции).

Точно так же ведут себя и [шаблонные функции с параметром](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QoEV7F8zrjYKjIx7):

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T) { }

template <typename T>
void f(T) { }
```

Приводит к ошибке:

> ```
> error: redefinition of 'f'
> ```

Однако, на каком варианте остановиться в итоге `T` или `const T` зависит от того, хотите ли вы поддерживать константность параметра внутри функции или нет. Но важно это только лишь при определении функции (реализации её тела), а не при объявлении.